# Criteria for a solvable septic equation

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, galois-theory

I have a certain 7x7 matrix whose elements are all symbolic, and I want to know the eigenvalues. I have to solve a septic equation, but it is generally impossible. However, I am only interested in the eigenvalues that are all integers, so I am attempting to find some constrains on the matrix elements (coefficient of the septic) so that its solutions are integers.
I have never studied group theory before so I might be saying something wrong, but according to my poor knowledge, a polynomial is solvable if the Galois group of the equation is a solvable group. Does this mean that there are certain criteria for the coefficients so that it can be solved analytically?

Comment: Anything septic is usually just a stinky proposition.

Comment: I will confirm however that your statement on solvable groups is correct.

Comment: I might be able to eliminate one or two degrees by assuming that one or two eigenvalues are zero from some previous data. I have to prove that, though.